# Guard starts then exits?

Tags: guard

I want to use guard to run my bacon tests, my `Gemfile` looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'slim'
gem 'puma'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'httparty'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'bacon'
  gem 'guard-bacon'
  gem 'libnotify'
  gem 'rb-inotify'
end
```

My `Guardfile` looks like

```
# parameters:
#  output     => the formatted to use
#  backtrace  => number of lines, nil =  everything
guard 'bacon', :output => "BetterOutput", :backtrace => 4 do
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "specs/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{specs/.+\.rb$})
end
```

When I run `guard` the following happens

```
$ guard
Bacon: Using output BetterOutput.
Bacon: Limiting backtrace to 4 lines.
09:02:05 - INFO - Guard uses Libnotify to send notifications.
09:02:05 - INFO - Guard uses TerminalTitle to send notifications.
09:02:05 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/martin/code/jse-api'
Guard::Bacon started.
[1] guard(main)> %                     
$
```

It seems to load everything, get to the guard prompt and exit.

I have no idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to the version of `guard` required by `guard-bacon 1.1.0`

If you force it to the latest version of guard

```
gem 'guard', '>= 1.8.0'
```

It falls back to a older version of `guard-bacon 1.0.5` and everything works.